EAS Build error when trying to build a (non Expo) React Native iOS app
When I run the following line trying to build a non Expo React Native app for iOS using EAS Build I get an error "Could not find target with id 'undefined' in project.pbxproj". I'm sure it's just a config error, but I'm not sure where the 'undefined' is pulling from. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
eas build --platform ios --profile staging
The response I get is as follows:
Loaded "env" configuration for the "staging" profile: REACT_APP_ENVIRONMENT, RECEIPT_URL_STAGE, RECEIPT_URL_PROD, NO_FLIPPER, APP_IDENTIFIER, EXPIRED_COOKIE. Learn more: https://docs.expo.dev/build-reference/variables/
» ios: paths-project-pbxproj: Found multiple project.pbxproj file paths, using "ios/XXXX.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj". Ignored paths: ["ios/PBXXXX/PBXXXX.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj"]
» ios: paths-project-pbxproj: Found multiple project.pbxproj file paths, using "ios/XXXX.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj". Ignored paths: ["ios/PBXXXX/PBXXXX.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj"]
» ios: paths-project-pbxproj: Found multiple project.pbxproj file paths, using "ios/XXXX.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj". Ignored paths: ["ios/PBXXXX/PBXXXX.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj"]
» ios: paths-project-pbxproj: Found multiple project.pbxproj file paths, using "ios/XXXX.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj". Ignored paths: ["ios/PBXXXX/PBXXXX.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj"]
» ios: paths-project-pbxproj: Found multiple project.pbxproj file paths, using "ios/XXXX.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj". Ignored paths: ["ios/PBXXXX/PBXXXX.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj"]
Could not find target with id 'undefined' in project.pbxproj
    Error: build command failed.

My eas.json file is as follows:
{
  "cli": {
    "version": ">= 10.2.2"
  },
  "build": {
    "development": {
      "developmentClient": true,
      "distribution": "internal",
      "ios": {
        "scheme": "Development",
        "cocoapods": "1.14.3"
      }
    },
    "staging": {
      "distribution": "internal",
      "env": {
        "REACT_APP_ENVIRONMENT": "stage",
        "RECEIPT_URL_STAGE": "https://xxxx/stage/api/receipt",
        "RECEIPT_URL_PROD": "https://xxxx/prod/api/receipt",
        "NO_FLIPPER": "true",
        "APP_IDENTIFIER": "com.xxxx.iphone.stage",
        "EXPIRED_COOKIE": "xxxx"
      },
      "ios": {
        "scheme": "Staging",
        "cocoapods": "1.14.3"
      }
    },
    "production": {
      "env": {
        "REACT_APP_ENVIRONMENT": "production",
        "RECEIPT_URL_STAGE": "https://xxxx/stage/api/receipt",
        "RECEIPT_URL_PROD": "https://xxxx/prod/api/receipt",
        "NO_FLIPPER": "true",
        "APP_IDENTIFIER": "com.xxxx.iphone"
      },
      "ios": {
        "scheme": "Production",
        "cocoapods": "1.14.3"
      }
    }
  },
  "submit": {
    "production": {}
  }
}

